# Why do I get ClassCastException?

Tags: java, oop, collections, classcastexception

I am trying this piece of code. Why do I get `ClassCastException` when I have initialized my set to contain elements of type `Object` which is directly or indirectly parent of all classes in Java?

```
 Set s = new TreeSet<Object>();
    
    s.add(10);
    s.add("ABC");
    System.out.println(s);
```

Comment: Please add the full stack trace of the exception to your question.

Comment: BTW Java Language Specification [4.8. Raw Types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se19/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.8-400): "*The use of raw types is allowed only as a concession to compatibility of legacy code. The use of raw types in code written after the introduction of generics into the Java programming language is strongly discouraged. It is possible that future versions of the Java programming language will disallow the use of raw types.*"

Comment: as [documented](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/util/TreeSet.html#%3Cinit%3E()): "*... all such elements must be mutually comparable: e1.compareTo(e2) must not throw a `ClassCastException` ...  If the user attempts to add an element to the set that violates this constraint (for example, the user attempts to add a string element to a set whose elements are integers), the add call will throw a `ClassCastException` ...*" (the documented example exactly describes the posted code)

Comment: and you should have searched before asking: [some results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjava%5D+TreeSet+ClassCastException) (for `[java] TreeSet ClassCastException`); pretty sure *one or two* are about this same problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the `Treeset` [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Comparable.html), if you don't supply a `Comparator` when creating the `TreeSet`, it will use the element's *natural ordering*.  That means that to determine the ordering of a pair of values, it will cast one value to `Comparable<?>` and then call `compareTo` to compare it to the other one.

In your example, the cast to `Comparable<?>` actually works, because both classes implement `Comparable`, albeit with different type parameters.

The problem is that `this.compareTo(v)` is defined to throw a `ClassCastException` when `this` and `v` are not comparable.  The [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo(T)) says:

> "**Throws:** `ClassCastException` - if the specified object's type prevents it from being compared to this object."

When `a` is `Double(10)` and `b` is `"ABC"` and you call `a.compareTo(b)`, the `Double.compareTo` method will attempt to cast `b` to `Double`.  *That cast* will throw a `ClassCastException`.

---

In short, if you want to use a `TreeSet` to hold a mixture of different types, you *must* define and supply a `Comparator` that can order *all* of the types / elements you are going to add to the set.

Answer (score 2):

`TreeSet` have to compare objects somehow. If you don't provide `Comparator` explicitly it will try to cast objects to `Comparable<T>`.

`String` is implementing `Comparable<String>` so when `TreeSet` calls `"ABC".compareTo(10)` java tries to cast `10` to `String` and fails.

You should either use `TreeSet` with objects that are comparable to each other, or provide explicit comparator.